# Are Apache Zeppelin websockets authenticated?

Tags: nginx, websocket, apache-zeppelin

Following the guidance here...

https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.2/setup/security/authentication_nginx.html

I used the nginx.conf (almost) verbatim to deploy Zeppelin behind an Nginx proxy to achieve basic authentication over https by nginx as a proxy to my internal, unprotected Zeppelin instance. My intent is to achieve confidentiality by using https up to nginx with upstream internal comms unencrypted--assuming all external communications are encrypted and authenticated. My impression from this Zeppelin site is that their guidance here achieves both by reasonable, but conservative modern security standards.

I'm concerned that the nginx auth proxy does not achieve for the websocket endpoint what it does for the https one. My question, (mostly for Zepp contributors) is, does this suggested Nginx authentication and https config do anything to protect the websocket channel from unauthorized use? Is authentication occurring by the Zeppelin server of the clients connecting to it via the /ws uri?

Link #2 here makes it sound like websockets /can/ be "secured", by enabling the system for authentication internal to Zepellin. This, however, would seem to go against the better advice of the Zeppelin team in the first link where they recommend separating authentication and Zeppelin concerns.

https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.2/security/shiroauthentication.html

So, can Zeppelin be hardened (as hard as basic auth can be) behind basic auth over https setup using Nginx? In other words, does Zeppelin authenticate websocket clients inside the ed or could an nginx-authenticated Zeppelin front end be spoofed in a way that websocket connections could be established without nginx requiring a password? How could this nginx.conf be changed to achieve a secure nginx-proxy for an non-https, non-wss Zeppelin upstream server?

```
upstream zeppelin {
    server 192.168.1.200:38080;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mysite.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/key/nginx_20191222.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/key/nginx_20191222.key;
    ssl_protocols   TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers     HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://zeppelin;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_redirect off;

        auth_basic        "Private site";
        auth_basic_user_file  conf.d/passwd;
    }

    location /ws {  
        proxy_pass http://zeppelin;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;    #websocket;
        proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;
    }
}
```

Comment: The initial connection will always be HTTP/HTTPS, before it is being upgraded to WS/WSS... but alike you describe the proxy setup, this does not sound alike end-to-end encryption.

Comment: But, is it possible using this configuration to make an initial connection direct to the /ws endpoint without requiring authentication to have viewed the http front end at all?

Comment: That's what [Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/configuration.html#apache-shiro-configuration) is for... you just need to remove `auth_basic` from the nginx.conf. The only problem is, that endpoint /ws does not sound encrypted - and so plain-text credentials may leak (even if only on your private network). If Zeppelin would have a publicly accessible IP address, one could sign off a SSL certificate, in order to have end-to-end encryption.

Comment: This post seems like relevant context. For Zeppelin developers: is WSS inherently supported and do you do any kind of "ticketing" or the like to validate new websocket requests--like what's discussed here? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websocket-security

Comment: Here's an [example](https://knox.apache.org/books/knox-1-2-0/user-guide.html#Zeppelin+UI) for a Knox configuration, which also suggests to import a self-signed certificate. Or here's [another one](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/How-to-enable-Knox-proxying-for-Zeppelin/ta-p/246094), which hints for that it doesn't work perfectly because of two bugs (not sure how actual this is).